# Clarifications on the limits of a client in Google Project

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-admin-sdk, google-developers-console

I am developing a multi customer application that uses Admin SDK to perform queries on customers' directory.

At the moment I have a single **google project** with a single **client id** for web application that is used by all the customers.

Each customer runs on a different subdomain `http://<customer>.myapp.com`. This required me to specify `http://<customer>.myapp.com` in the `Authorized JavaScript origins` list.

- Is there a limit on the amount of entries that `Authorized JavaScript origins` list can have?
- Is there an API to add items to `Authorized JavaScript origins` list?
- Is there a limit on the amount of customers that can authenticate using a single client id?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a limit on the amount of entries that Authorized JavaScript origins list can have? can you get the limit of the ids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a limit on the amount of entries that Authorized JavaScript origins list can have?

To my knowledge there is no limit but i have heard a rumor that its 200 i have never bothered to test this.

> Is there an API to add items to Authorized JavaScript origins list?

There is no api for adding editing that in the Google developer console it must be done manually.

> Is there a limit on the amount of customers that can authenticate using a single client id?

there is no limit